# Can I get access to the JMS on non-EE java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

As the title states, I want to use the JMS to interact with a queue server(rabbitmq and apollo, for testing) but I read that JMS is included in Java EE.  Is there a library or way I can get access to it without EE? I am just using the standard JDK that comes with mac(I don't see the EE avail for mac on the download page).

Comment: you can find some older versions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eesdk-419427.html#java_ee_sdk-5_08-jdk-6u17-nojdk-oth-ml-JPR)

Comment: You can install Unix version on Mac OS X. http://java.sun.com/javaee/sdk/javaee6sdk_install.jsp

Answer (score 0):

A possible option would be to use the client library which is offered by RabbitMQ (http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html).
This way you can simply connect to a RabbitMQ server/queue.

But I'm not sure if this library can be used to connect to other JMS implementations than RabbitMQ.